# Positioning views so that each one of them takes the same space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to a position a couple of views(let's say N) in a line, so that each one of them will take 1/N of the width of the screen. I'm aware how to achieve this using LinearLayout(`layoutWeight`), but the thing is that I need to have another layouts that will appear below certain views that are in this line. The thing is that since all these views are wrapped into a LinearLayout I can't place my additional layouts inside this layout (for obvious reasons), and I can't refer to a particular view from the LinearLayout and place my views below it. Some visual aid in order to help explaining myself:

[image]

So I want to display the grey box exactly below the third box above. Currently I achieve this by getting the screen width and dividing it into N equal parts and setting the appropriate margin to this view. However, I don't like this very much. Is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: Are those rows? and a button underneath?

Comment: It is a single row that has N items and each one of them takes 1/N from the width. The gray button underneath should actually be a couple of buttons/i.e another LinearLayout/ which should be positioned exactly under the i-th button from the above menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to have one View or ViewGroup positioned so that its center is directly below the center of the third box?

Its possible but not very elegant:

The idea is to use a table layout and android:layout_span to join 3 cells in the second row and use a centered view inside that table span.

Example table layout:

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="4" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="0" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button 1,2,3" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="4" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is my idea since xml on android is really hard.

Inside the linear layout create 2 parts inside of it 1 linear layout and the other a relative layout use LayoutWeight to separate both of them using the original linear layout.

Comment: Can't happen because the button below is/might be wider than 1/N of the screen width. :\

Comment: Okay uhh inside the relative layout add in uhh tableLayout that should make the rows adjustable and stretch out to the maximum of that bottom portion otherwise try using linear layout instead of relative layout.